# C#, Nest, Need to map to both ElasticSearch 2.* and ElasticSearch 5.*+

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I've run into a bit of an issue and I'm hoping someone knows a simple answer.

I am in a situation where I have C#/Nest code that when running in one environment needs to write to Elastic 2.* and in another environment, it needs to write to 5.x. The issue is that the version of Nest I am using, always writes .NET strings as "text". I would like a way to write the strings as a "string" if I am writing to 2.x and as "Text" if writing to 5.x and above.

We will be upgrading all of our Elastic environments to 6.x soon so this is only a temporary measure. Also, this is a large number of different objects so I would prefer a one time option. In other words, I don't want to have to map each and every field.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use dynamic objects and let Elasticsearch infer mapping or do you have strict dependency?

Comment: We've run into issues with fields being inferred incorrectly so we prefer explicit mapping.

Comment: Dynamic templates could be an option but probably will have to write to new index as local mapping overrides template mapping if I remember correctly